# vb.net and mysql database search button for listview

Tags: mysql, vb.net, listview

i dont know how to make a search button for vb.net with database mysql for listview i have been searching in the net for answers but i cant understand any of it

on my textbox i put keyup on it so i can search faster the problem is how do i code the search? help me with the logic and on how to use them

heres the code on how i preview my data on listview

Sub loadmeds()

```
    ds = New DataSet
    da = New MySqlDataAdapter("select * from tblmeds", conn)
    da.Fill(ds, "tblmeds")

    Listmed.Items.Clear()
    If ds.Tables("tblmeds").Rows.Count > 0 Then

        For i As Integer = 0 To ds.Tables("tblmeds").Rows.Count - 1
            With Listmed.Items.Add(ds.Tables("tblmeds").Rows(i).Item(0).ToString)
                .SubItems.Add(ds.Tables("tblmeds").Rows(i).Item(1).ToString)
                .SubItems.Add(ds.Tables("tblmeds").Rows(i).Item(2).ToString)
                .SubItems.Add(ds.Tables("tblmeds").Rows(i).Item(3).ToString)
                .SubItems.Add(ds.Tables("tblmeds").Rows(i).Item(4).ToString)
                Dim MyDate As DateTime = CDate(ds.Tables("tblmeds").Rows(i).Item(5).ToString)
                .SubItems.Add(MyDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"))
                MyDate = CDate(ds.Tables("tblmeds").Rows(i).Item(6).ToString)
                .SubItems.Add(MyDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"))
            End With
        Next
    End If
```

Comment: The ListView is suboptimal for dbOps.  Using a DataGridView bound to a datasource, you just need to apply a filter...2 lines of code

Comment: if i use datagrid sir then my whole system is doomed each form has listview on it although i like listview more the fact that it has clean white color

Comment: What really "dooms" your app is storing everything as string: dates, counts, price etc.  A DataTable and DGV will store properly typed data

Comment: what should i do about it? its a Point of sale and inventory